# Why is an empty InMemoryUploadedFile object received when the same file is uploaded consecutively

Tags: python, django

I have a script that sends a POST request to Django for uploading files. It runs indefinitely and uploads a file "file1.csv".

```
files ={"uploadedfile": ("file1.csv", open("file1.csv", 'rb'))}
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Now when django receives file1.csv the first time, I can read the contents and the size isn't zero.

```
payload = request.FILES
file = payload['uploadedfile']
print "File size:", file.size
```

Output:

```
File size: 1758
```

But when I receive the file the second time in a ***new POST request*** (since the uploading script is running in an infinite loop), the file is empty.

```
File size: 0
```

I don't understand the behavior. Any ideas?

I tried uploading multiple different files as well. Whenever the same file is uploaded `n` number of times after the first time, the InMemoryUploadedFile object is always empty.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into similar problems before. This happens if you execute the following line once

```
files ={"uploadedfile": ("file1.csv", open("file1.csv", 'rb'))}
```

and the next line which involves uploading more than once.

```
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I guess you are running the above from an interpreter and thinking that you can create the `files` dictionary once and upload many times. It won't work! Moreover, this has not got anything to do with Django.

So, before each upload create your `files` dictionary afresh and you should be good.

Comment: Still more than 5 years after, your answer is still accurate. I spent hours trying to find a solution regarding this issue! In practice my code was working as expected, but I was not able to make my tests pass... Damnit I wish I found your answer earlier! :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Simply do `file.seek(0)`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Relevant source code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile

Answer (score 0):

Is your file is larger than 2.5 megabytes?

By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. This means that saving the file involves only a read from memory and a write to disk and thus is very fast.

However, if an uploaded file is too large, Django will write the uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your system’s temporary directory. On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to generate a file called something like /tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload. If an upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django streams the data onto disk.

These specifics – 2.5 megabytes; /tmp; etc. – are simply “reasonable defaults” which can be customized as described in the next section.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) is insturctions for Django file uploads. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. No, the file isn't greater than 2.5 MB. Its a few kBs. I tried experimenting with both InMemoryFile and TemporaryFile location storage, both result in the same thing. This is baffling!